# Dropdown menu on navigation bar disappears behind when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is the website I am trying to set up: http://koralhassan.com
I have adjusted the template to make the CV section a hover-dropdown section. However, when I scroll down, the dropdown menu no longer appears when hovering. I am trying to find a way to either make the it appear, or make the dropdown expand to the right of the CV section instead of below it (which I think would also solve the problem). I have very little programming knowledge so please don't throw me in the deep end. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class *.w3-bar* has property *overflow: hidden*.

Remove it and it should be fine.

Comment: How do I do that? Iremoved it from line 63 of w3.css but it didn't work. Like I said, I'm _really_ new to this stuff!

Comment: @Larok00 check this screenshot http://prntscr.com/h5fuyu. Make sure to save it and maybe do a hard refresh CTRL + SHIFT + R.

Comment: I highlighted the css property "overflow: hidden", that is the problem. Remove it and then save and hard refresh.

Comment: Ok so I changed the line you highlighted to this:  <div class="w3-bar w3-card w3-animate-top w3-white" id="myNavbar">

and I deleted overflow:hidden on line 63, it's still not working for some reason? When I press f12 overflow:hidden is still there. When I go to edit the file, I can see I have removed it. I don't understand.

Comment: Maybe you are not removing it in the correct place. Make sure you are editing the correct files.

Comment: I got it now, I was using this link as reference for the stylesheet: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css

I changed it now to the internal one. Thanks a lot for the help! On another note is there a way to do it without changing the properties of the bar thing? I know there something like adding an attribute with !important attached somewhere? If there's another way like this, could you show me?

Comment: You could add to css class ".w3-animate-top" the property "overflow: visible". Make sure to upvote this post and if it is solved, mark it as solved.